# Convert windows R package to linux usage

Tags: r, package

I want to convert certain R packages (which have been installed under windows) for linux usage, then I can simply upload these R package to the linux server, and therefore it is not necessary to install these R packages again under linux environment.

I wonder that is it doable?

Comment: While this may doable, why do you think it would be _desirable_?  R has a good package manager already, which does a good job of keeping dependencies up to date etc.  I might prefer just installing what I need on each platform separately.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not. Many are precompiled binaries for windows, but need to be compiled in linux. Especially those packages that contain compiled code (such as C or C++), these need to be compiled on the target platform so that they are linked to that platform's libraries.

If the issue is the time it takes to maintain a set of packages, one thing you can do is create your own utilities package, which imports all of the packages you would want. Then, if you install your utilities package, it will automatically install all of the others.